# mBed C++ Using an RtosTimer inside of an RtosThread

Tags: c++, multithreading, timer, rtos, mbed

I am writing some software to control a quadcopter and have got completely stuck with RtosTimers. I am getting the error "Error: No instance of constructor "rtos::RtosTimer::RtosTimer" matches the argument list in "flightController.h", Line: 13, Col: 29"

I have looked at the example code in the handbook and my code seems to match. I have also googled but I couldn't find anything on using RtosTimers inside of RtosThreads.

Maybe I am going about this the wrong way so if anyone has any suggestions it would be much appreciated.

Here is the code that is causing me problems

```
//Rtos Timers
RtosTimer UpdateFlightTimer(Task500Hz, osTimerPeriodic, (void *)0);
RtosTimer UpdateCommandTimer(Task50Hz, osTimerPeriodic, (void *)0);

// A thread to monitor the serial ports
void FlightControllerThread(void const *args) 
{  
UpdateFlightTimer.start(2);
UpdateCommandTimer.start(20);

// Wait here forever
Thread::wait(osWaitForever);
}

void Task500Hz(void const *n)
{
//Get IMU data and convert to yaw, pitch, roll
_freeIMU.getQ(_rawQuaternion);
_freeIMU.getRate(_gyroRate);
GetAttitude();

//Rate mode
if(_rate == true && _stab == false)
{
    //Update rate PID process value with gyro rate
    _yawRatePIDController->setProcessValue(_gyroRate[0]);
    _pitchRatePIDController->setProcessValue(_gyroRate[2]);
    _rollRatePIDController->setProcessValue(_gyroRate[1]);

    //Update rate PID set point with desired rate from RC
    _yawRatePIDController->setSetPoint(_rcConstrainedCommands[0]);
    _pitchRatePIDController->setSetPoint(_rcConstrainedCommands[1]);
    _rollRatePIDController->setSetPoint(_rcConstrainedCommands[2]);

    //Compute rate PID outputs
    _ratePIDControllerOutputs[0] = _yawRatePIDController->compute();
    _ratePIDControllerOutputs[1] = _pitchRatePIDController->compute();
    _ratePIDControllerOutputs[2] = _rollRatePIDController->compute();
}
//Stability mode
else
{
    //Update stab PID process value with ypr
    _yawStabPIDController->setProcessValue(_yrp[0]);
    _pitchStabPIDController->setProcessValue(_yrp[2]);
    _rollStabPIDController->setProcessValue(_yrp[1]);

    //Update stab PID set point with desired angle from RC
    _yawStabPIDController->setSetPoint(_yawTarget);
    _pitchStabPIDController->setSetPoint(_rcConstrainedCommands[1]);
    _rollStabPIDController->setSetPoint(_rcConstrainedCommands[2]);

    //Compute stab PID outputs
    _stabPIDControllerOutputs[0] = _yawStabPIDController->compute();
    _stabPIDControllerOutputs[1] = _pitchStabPIDController->compute();
    _stabPIDControllerOutputs[2] = _rollStabPIDController->compute();

    //if pilot commanding yaw
    if(abs(_rcConstrainedCommands[0]) > 5)
    {  
        _stabPIDControllerOutputs[0] = _rcConstrainedCommands[0];  //Feed to rate PID     (overwriting stab PID output)
        _yawTarget = _yrp[0];
    }

    //Update rate PID process value with gyro rate
    _yawRatePIDController->setProcessValue(_gyroRate[0]);
    _pitchRatePIDController->setProcessValue(_gyroRate[2]);
    _rollRatePIDController->setProcessValue(_gyroRate[1]);

    //Update rate PID set point with desired rate from stab PID
    _yawRatePIDController->setSetPoint(_stabPIDControllerOutputs[0]);
    _pitchRatePIDController->setSetPoint(_stabPIDControllerOutputs[1]);
    _rollRatePIDController->setSetPoint(_stabPIDControllerOutputs[2]);

    //Compute rate PID outputs
    _ratePIDControllerOutputs[0] = _yawRatePIDController->compute();
    _ratePIDControllerOutputs[1] = _pitchRatePIDController->compute();
    _ratePIDControllerOutputs[2] = _rollRatePIDController->compute();
}


//Calculate motor power if flying
if(_rcCommands[3] > 0 && _armed == true)
{
    _motorPower[0] = Constrain(_rcConstrainedCommands[3] + _ratePIDControllerOutputs[1] + _ratePIDControllerOutputs[2] + _ratePIDControllerOutputs[0], MOTORS_MIN, MOTORS_MAX);
    _motorPower[1] = Constrain(_rcConstrainedCommands[3] + _ratePIDControllerOutputs[1] - _ratePIDControllerOutputs[2] - _ratePIDControllerOutputs[0], MOTORS_MIN, MOTORS_MAX);
    _motorPower[2] = Constrain(_rcConstrainedCommands[3] - _ratePIDControllerOutputs[1] - _ratePIDControllerOutputs[2] + _ratePIDControllerOutputs[0], MOTORS_MIN, MOTORS_MAX);
    _motorPower[3] = Constrain(_rcConstrainedCommands[3] - _ratePIDControllerOutputs[1] + _ratePIDControllerOutputs[2] - _ratePIDControllerOutputs[0], MOTORS_MIN, MOTORS_MAX);
}
//Not flying
else
{
    //Disable motors
    _motorPower[0] = MOTORS_OFF;
    _motorPower[1] = MOTORS_OFF;
    _motorPower[2] = MOTORS_OFF;
    _motorPower[3] = MOTORS_OFF;

    _notFlying ++;
    if(_notFlying > 200) //Not flying for 1 second
    {
        //Reset iteratior
        _notFlying = 0;

        //Zero gyro
        _freeIMU.zeroGyro();

        //Reset I
        _yawRatePIDController->reset();
        _pitchRatePIDController->reset();
        _rollRatePIDController->reset();
        _yawStabPIDController->reset();
        _pitchStabPIDController->reset();
        _rollStabPIDController->reset();
    }
} 

//Set motor power
_motor1.write(_motorPower[0]);
_motor2.write(_motorPower[1]);
_motor3.write(_motorPower[2]);
_motor4.write(_motorPower[3]);
```

}

```
void Task50Hz(void const *n)
{
//Get RC control values

//Constrain
//Rate mode
if(_rate == true && _stab == false)
{
    _rcConstrainedCommands[0] = Constrain(_rcCommands[0], RC_YAW_RATE_MIN, RC_YAW_RATE_MAX);
    _rcConstrainedCommands[1] = Constrain(_rcCommands[1], RC_PITCH_RATE_MIN, RC_PITCH_RATE_MAX);
    _rcConstrainedCommands[2] = Constrain(_rcCommands[2], RC_ROLL_RATE_MIN, RC_ROLL_RATE_MAX);
    _rcConstrainedCommands[3] = Constrain(_rcCommands[3], RC_THRUST_MIN, RC_THRUST_MAX);
}
else
{
    _rcConstrainedCommands[0] = Constrain(_rcCommands[0], RC_YAW_RATE_MIN, RC_YAW_RATE_MAX);
    _rcConstrainedCommands[1] = Constrain(_rcCommands[1], RC_PITCH_ANGLE_MIN, RC_PITCH_ANGLE_MAX);
    _rcConstrainedCommands[2] = Constrain(_rcCommands[2], RC_ROLL_ANGLE_MIN, RC_ROLL_ANGLE_MAX);
    _rcConstrainedCommands[3] = Constrain(_rcCommands[3], RC_THRUST_MIN, RC_THRUST_MAX);
}
}
```

My program can be found at http://mbed.org/users/joe4465/code/QuadMK5/

And the problem is in flightController.h I think it should be clear what I am trying to do but if anyone isn't sure let me know.

I also have another totally unrelated problem. I can set my PID variables over serial and then save them to a config file but 1 in 3 times if will hang just after it has saved the data to the file and I'm not sure why. Does anyone have any idea what could cause this?

Thanks Joe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to put void const *n in the parameters of the functions where they are defined at the top